# How to limit current of transformer to protect rectifier?

Tags: power-supply

Lets suppose that I got a transformer with a 3.3A output. The transformer is then used in a circuit that includes a rectifier that can tolerate a max draw of 3A. What would be the best solution for limiting the current without risking damaging the rectifier. Could a limiting resistor be used or would a thermistor be better? Any other solutions would be appreciated.

**NOTE: We prefer not to drop the voltage in the circuit**

[image]

Comment: What load is the rectifier supplying? What maximum current is it likely to draw?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization (i.e., *"What is the best ...?"*) require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumpation, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Answer (score 1):

I would be far more worried about overloading your 3.3 A transformer than over loading a 3 A rectifier. Just use a slow-blow fuse.

Answer (score 0):

A fuse is the obvious answer, but if you are expecting to routinely draw more than the limit, you can use a PTC thermistor that rises in resistance as the temperature rises (as a result of the current). You'd need to choose one that has a similar or shorter thermal time constant than the rectifier such that it responds before damage is done to the diodes. Most diodes will tolerate a significant overload for short periods, but depending on the construction of the bridge, the thermal mass can keep the rate of rise of the junctions low. [image]

Comment: Some points on the PTC- they have a wide variance (almost 2:1) over temperature extremes, so if the equipment ambient temperature varies widely you have to take that into consideration.  Also  depending on their construction some have fast response times, others not so much.

Comment: Good points, but what you generally want to limit is not current, but the temperature that the component you're protecting reaches, so a faster response at high ambients isn't a bad thing.

Comment: For rectifiers the junction will be destroyed primarily through overcurrent, that's always been a problem on any power semiconductor- getting the heat out the junction- you'll never see it in as an ambient spike. That's one reason the pulse characteristics have magnitudes higher current limits, but there's a pulse length/duty cycle limit attached.  Transformers can take current hits but have much better thermal sinking due to all that copper and iron mass, so they can take abuse basically until the primary (for a step down) opens (either wire or thermal fuse).